# SignalR: Concurrent connections on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

I have a self-hosted WebAPI which uses SignalR. The process is running on a **client OS** (Windows 7). Let's assume most clients fall back to long-polling. How many clients can I roughly have? I'm asking because I [read](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx) Microsoft keeps concurrent connections artificially low on client OS (the article is about IIS though)...

In this regard does it matter whether or not clients are using long-polling or WebSockets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer regarding request limits for self-hosting on Win 7, but I can say that there can be a difference between long-polling and WebSockets since with long-polling, you can use up several requests at a time, while the WebSockets connection always uses one.

I suspect that the IIS connection limits are not enforced when self-hosting with OWIN, so you'd deal with the ASP.NET limits (defaulting at 5000 concurrent requests per CPU) which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance).

Since long-polling can use a variable number of concurrent requests, it's not possible to say how many clients you can have exactly; it depends on what the clients do. So you'll have to estimate or measure based on typical usage scenarios.