# Can we force SignalR to use long polling connection method

Tags: c#, signalr

We are currently using signalR in our application. It works great if I am the only one using the application, but it completely breaks when more than two person using the application simultaneously.

This happens due to the limitation in IIS concurrent connection.

**IIS Concurrent Requests Limit**

> Windows 8 (Basic edition) -   3
>
> Windows 8 Professional, Enterprise - 10
>
> Windows 7 Home Starter -1
>
> Windows 7 Basic - 1
>
> Windows 7 Premium - 3
>
> Windows 7 Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise - 10
>
> Windows Vista Home Basic (IIS process activation and HTTP processing
>   only) - 3
>
> Windows Vista Home Premium - 3
>
> Windows Vista Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise - 10
>
> Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 and
>   Windows
>
> Server 2012 allow an unlimited amount of simultaneously requests.*

Now I want to force the signalR to use the Long Polling connection in order to overcome the IIS limitation. Is there any way to force the connection method?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994776/signalr-how-do-i-disable-websockets?

Comment: For production usage, it's better to use a windows server.

Comment: @L-Three Yes I checked that one. Instead of disconnecting the client can we force them to connect/reconnect using long polling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```

Check [Specifying a transport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#specifying-a-transport).

Also I suggest you to use [SignalR Self-Host](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) which is not using IIS limits because of OWIN.

Check here [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24726260/3432471).

Comment: is it possible to specify polling interval?